# For Jetpack Compose Tv the remote switches not working in page where i show video view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack, jetpack-compose-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-tv

For Jetpack Compose Tv the remote switches not working in page where i show video view
Like in home page i was able to select different cards and by clicking it i am able to navigate to showMovie page but in there video is playing but  not able to pause because the  remote switches  not working

I have tried adding focusable clickable and onkeyEvent in modifier

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [mre]? This will help us pinpoint the cause of the issue and offer better guidance.